# Are all conic equations functions?

Tags: functions, conic-sections

Just wondering why we have equations defined in the Cartesian coordinate for circles and ellipses: wouldn't graphing those shapes contradict the fundamental property of a function (i.e.: to each element in the domain corresponds a single element in the codomain)?

I know I can *algebraically* restate the equations as a function of y, but that would leave me with a square root whose domain I don't know, so the problem remains.

Comment: No, they are not functions. However, you can represent them using a couple of functions. a circle x^2+y^2=1 can be represented as y=sqrt(1-x^2) and y=-sqrt(1-x^2)

Comment: They are functions when we talk 3D. The independent variables x,y and dependent variable Z. So the function of two vraibles f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 would be a circle if we said that z can be only equal to 1

Comment: It's pretty obvious the graph of a circle is not the graph of a function.  Why should this be a problem?  Circles are nevertheless useful/interesting.

Comment: @Sorfosh: So if a circle/ellipse graphed in three dimensions can be a function, then a sphere/ellipsoid can also be a function in 4D (although we couldn't picture that)?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys by the way.

Comment: @matt24 i am not 100% sure but i think so, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conic sections are *relations*, not functions.

An equation (like for example $x^2 + y^2 = 100$) can be thought of as a criterion or condition that can be used to check any point to see if it is part of the relation.  For this example, $(7,4)$ is *not* part of the relation (because $7^2 + 4^2 ≠ 100$) but $(6, 8)$ *is* part of the relation (because $6^2 + 8^2 = 100$).

A function is a relation with the special, additional property that to each $x$ value in the domain there is one and only one corresponding $y$ value.  But relations in general don't have to meet that additional requirement; in a general relation, there can be lots of different $y$ values corresponding to a single $x$ value.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a conic describes a set of points in the 
Cartesian plane, $\{(x,y)|f(x,y)=0\}$, where $f$ is a function of *two* variables. You're right that for many conics there's no function $g:x\mapsto y$ of one variable that describes the same set of points. That doesn't diminish the utility of those equations, though.